# How to set flatpickr Time Picker with limits across two days?

Tags: javascript, flatpickr

I'm using flatpickr to allow for time input. I want to limit the time input from 3:00 PM to 3:00 AM (so I want to include 4:00 PM, 5:00 PM... 11:00 PM, 12:00 PM, 1:00 AM...).

Current code:

```
flatpickr({enableTime: true, noCalendar: true, dateFormat: "H:i", minTime: "15:00", maxTime: "3:00"})
```

I have also tried `minTime: "15:00", maxTime: "27:00"`

But neither of them work. [Documentation](https://flatpickr.js.org/) of flatpickr.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, at the current moment there is no way to achieve the behaviour you are describing with the native `config` and `minTime, maxTime, minDate, maxDate` props. (I would recommend opening a ticket in their repo: [flatpickr repo](https://github.com/flatpickr/flatpickr/blob/95785c66bf91f53e0c2fdc07ef4ed186bcbf7369/src/plugins/minMaxTimePlugin.ts))

You can, however utilize this workaround:

```
const instanceOfPickr = flatpickr("#works", {
      onValueUpdate: function(obj, updatedTime) {
        if ((updatedTime > "03:00") && (updatedTime < "15:00")) {
          instanceOfPickr.setDate(new Date("June 10, 2019 15:00:00"));
        }
      },
      enableTime: true,
      noCalendar: true,
      time_24hr: true,
    });
```

It is pretty clunky, but it will get the job done.

The only issues with it is - if you click on `decrease arrow` on hours or minutes when time is set to `15:00`, it will remain there. If you want to add `decrease` behaviour to those arrows to drop time to `03:00` - you can look specifically for them in the DOM and assign `setDate(new Date("June 10, 2019 03:00:00")` to the instance of your TimePicker.

Hope it helps.